# Wrong align for two divs

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have a problem with my HTML/CSS code. I have 2 divs ( you can see them in the photo ). I want to align them like it's shown in the second photo. My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>---</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/animatii.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu_active_zone">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <button class="buton_login">AUTENTIFICARE / INREGISTRARE</button>
            <br>
            <div class="box_fl">fdsdsfd</div>
            </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #888;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.menu h1{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #888;
    font-family: "Roboto Thin";
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.menu_active_zone{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box_fl{
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #888;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;


}

.buton_login{
    background: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #888;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888;
    float: right; 
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

[image: Capture 1]

[image: What I want to create]

Comment: Post the rest of your html/css for that area so that we have a [mcve] of what you're working with currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
box_fl{
height: auto;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #888;
display: none;
position: absolute; 

right: 0; 
bottom: 0;


}

.buton_login{
background: #fff;
height: 30px;
box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #888;
border: 0px;
font-family: "Roboto";
font-size: 16px;
color: #888;
float: right; 
position: relative; 
top:50px;
left:170px;
padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: You have to add top and left to position

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have the same result with the second div. Just the first was moved to the bottom side of the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the information that you provide. If I understand, you want to center and align vertically the 2 divs. If it is what your looking for. Here is my purpose. First, HTML code :

```
<body>
   <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu_active_zone">
      <h1>Title</h1> 
        <div id="login">
          <button class="buton_login">AUTENTIFICARE / INREGISTRARE</button>
          <div class="box_fl">fdsdsfd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I added another div with an id `#login`. This div allows you to align the divs vertically. Then, CSS code :

```
  .menu
  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #login
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Just to illustrate the mechanism to center and vertical alignement with the use of **Flexbox**. It displays HTML elements as blocks vertically or horizontally.

- **display** : flex indicates to use Flexbox (By default it display elements in a row)
- **flex-direction** : column, row indicates how to display the elements
- **justify-content** : center indicates to center elements on the 1rst axis
- **align-items** : center indicates to center elements on the 2nd axis

Hope you can integrate that on your code and that's what you are looking for.

Good luck !